# Python how to find an object by its attributes?

Tags: python

Is there a way to get an object by matching it up with its attributes? 
For example:

```
class band:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number


rivers = band("rivers", 1)
patrick = band("pat" , 2)
brian = band("brian" , 3)
scott = band("scott", 4)
```

In this code, is there a way for me to use a number(lets say 1), to find the object rivers within the band class and get its name attribute?

Thank you for taking your time to read this and have a nice day.

Comment: *from the class* - you meant *within* a class or something else?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: fix the indentation

Answer (score 0):

> In this code, is there a way for me to use a number(lets say 1), to find the object rivers within the band class and get its name attribute?

In this code, NO. Because you do not save the value of `name` to the class property.

However, if your class structure was like:

```
class band:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name   # <--- Here is the difference
```

you could have done it. Let say `rivers`, `patrick`, `brian` and `scott` are part of the list as:

```
my_list = [rivers, patrick, brian, scott]
```

Iterate over the list and print the `name` of class for which value of `number` is `1` as:

```
for item in my_list:
    if item.number == 1:
        print item.name
```

Comment: Alright, will try it this way in my project that I am currently working on.

Comment: Whoops, just realised I forgot to add self.name = name, I'll edit that in

Answer (score 0):

You may store a dictionary mapping number to band in order to achieve that.

For example

```
bands = {}

class band:
   def __init__(self, name, number):
      self.number = number
      self.name = name
      bands[number] = self

def getBandFromNumber(number):
   return bands[number]
```

Comment: It will be even better to put `bands` as class variable to the band class